# Unity External Dependency Manager resolution error while trying resolve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, admob, game-engine

When I try to do Force Resolve with "External Dependency Manager" it gives resolution failed.
It says "Gradle failed to fetch dependencies."
And I can't use Admob because of it.

I am using macOs Sonoma 14.0.

Long version of the error:

Failed to run '/Users/yakuperdem19/Documents/GitHub/kurye/Courier/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/gradlew --no-daemon -b "/Users/yakuperdem19/Documents/GitHub/kurye/Courier/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.10f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=/Users/yakuperdem19/Documents/GitHub/kurye/Courier/Assets/Plugins/Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2;[https://maven.google.com/"](https://maven.google.com/%22) "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.3.0;com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.1.0;com.onesignal:OneSignal:5.0.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=7.1.2"'
stdout:

stderr:
The operation couldn���t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

exit code: 1

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.kQMyrbEl9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.aZu50wZjTO/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1076)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStorey1:<>m__2 (GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.aZu50wZjTO/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:459)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStorey1/c__AnonStorey3:<>m__0 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.aZu50wZjTO/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:572)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.kQMyrbEl9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:486)
Google.RunOnMainThread:m__1 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.kQMyrbEl9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:536)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.kQMyrbEl9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested (bool) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.kQMyrbEl9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.kQMyrbEl9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:362)

Comment: You do not have the right version of Java.  Install Java like error message says.

Comment: @jdweng How do I install java to unity?

Comment: Well you can point to the existing correct version in settings or you could install it using hub or do it yourself and point it.

Comment: See link above "exit code 1"

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @BugFinder's suggestion that you properly set up Unity's Java version, once you have confirmed a successful installation and have pointed Unity at it, make sure to uncheck and recheck the JDK path in the external tools settings menu as described in the [EDM4U Debugging Guide](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/troubleshooting-faq.md#jdk-sdk-ndk-gradle-issues-including-locating).

After you have done so, if issues continue, proceed through the rest of the [EDM4U troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/troubleshooting-faq.md#edm4u-usage-troubleshooting-guide).